# I came across this excellent curriculum vitae. Do you know what template it uses?

Tags: templates, cv, currvita

As read in the title, I found this amazing [CV](https://www.eng.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ea28wong/AWong_CV.pdf) online. It organizes each section neatly with very pleasant layouts. Do you know what template it uses?
[image: List of Content]
[image: Personal Data]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you considered contacting Alexander Wong directly? After all, his contact information is easy to find...

Comment: I doubt there's any good way to determine the template from the PDF output alone. Plus, the author might've created his CV from scratch, without the use of a template.

Comment: Welcome. // By structure this is pretty much an ordinary document, e.g. based on the article class. So just write your CV with that and fine-tune appearance later. E.g. use some package from here https://ctan.org/topic/headings to change sections, fonts etc. After all, you should be fluent enough with standard LaTeX, e.g. from a book on this subject. This one will bring you a long way towards this CV: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX .

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709348/i-came-across-this-excellent-curriculum-vitae-do-you-know-what-template-it-uses#comment1764145_709348) here's one way to do it. As you will see, this CV is just a regular document, where I put sometimes dummy-text, sometimes copies from the CV you linked to.

View this answer as an intermediate step of the total journey:

- write an ordinary document (sketched)
- do some finetuning on fonts, layout etc. (in progress)
- finalize (to be done)

#### Preamble

Package `hyperref` is very versatile. It lets you set document properties (check with a pdf-viewer), link color (i.e. TOC color) etc.

`booktabs` is a recommended style, if you'd go for a book. Just compare the more professional look of the table compared to a word processor.

I introduced some `macros` as shortcuts. Not only for demonstration you'll see both, a manual entry and a standardized one from deriving and using such macros.

Layout you still have to adjust, like setting paper format and margins. Use package `geometry` for this purpose.

Set your `default font` here. See e.g. answer [from Lev Bishop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2097/245790) or [Font typefaces on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces).

#### Intermediate result

[image: result]

Texmakers view:
[image: texmaker]

#### Titlepage

Just use the titlepage environment and typeset this page. There are many ways to do it. Here I deliberately ignored variables `\author`, `\title` etc.

#### Sections with rules

There are many ways to obtain them. See e.g. [(ignoring) Komascript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581566/section-formatting-with-boxed-numbering-and-horizontal-line/581572#581572) , [some custom style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621847/custom-section-style),  [etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsection-titles%5D%20rule)

For the "EDUCATION ..." I just used a lazy approach. There are many ways to obtain the tablular-like list of universities. E.g. you could use a table, but there's little common structure to it, demanding for a complicated table-set. So I choosed a lazy approach again, which can't be refactored easily into a `\newcommand` ... which origines from the authors non-systematic approach.

#### Reserach interest ...

and elsewhere are simply nested lists, without need to fine-tune layout to match the original.

However, watch my `REMARKs` within the code, below.

#### Selected ... presentations

It can be typeset as an enumerated list with some redefinition. If you'd spend more effort, you could even remove the trailing `.`; however, it doesen't hurt much.

#### Awards ...

shows you the direct (inlie) typesetting as well as its refatoring into a macro. However, the format chosen in the original may not be the most legible one. However, kindly see the effect on the source code, where both entries have the same effect:

```
\subsection{AWARDS}
% ~~~ directly ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\textbf{IMPACT 50} \hfill April 2020\par
\hspace{1ex}\textit{insideBIGDATA}\par
\textit{Awarded as Co-founder of DarwinAI for being one of the\\industry’s top 50 most impactful companies}
\bigskip

% ~~~ with above's macro, i.e. refactored ~~~~~~~~~~
\awrd{AI 100}
    {March 2020}
    {CB Insights}
    {Awarded as Co-founder of DarwinAI for being\\one of 100 most promising AI startups in the world}
```

[image: awards]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% ~~~ packages ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage[pdftitle={CV},              % you want tnis with pdf's
            pdfauthor={My Name Is},     % setting document properties
            pdfkeywords={CV, medical, AI, Professor},
            colorlinks=true,linkcolor={blue}]   % blue TOC
            {hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % recommended
\usepackage{lipsum}     % blindtext

% ~~~ some shortcuts, refactoring from back to front ~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\corg[3]{\item #1, #2 #3}% function, conference, abbrev
\newcommand\edpos[3]{\corg{#1}{#2}{#3}}% just re-using
\newcommand\cmmt[2]{\item #1 at University of Waterloo (#2)}% what when

\newcommand\awrd[4]{\textbf{#1} \hfill #2\par%
    \hspace{1ex}\textit{#3}\par\textit{#4}}

% ~~~ layout ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\parindent0pt
% ... you also may want to \usepackage{geometry}

% ~~~ fonts ~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{helvet}                         % if you prefer that
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}   % sans serif


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
% ~~~ TYPESETTING TITLE PAGE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{titlepage}
 \vspace*{3cm}
 \begin{center}
  \textbf{\Huge{Curriculum Vitae}}
  \vspace{1cm}
  
  \textbf{My name is, P.Eng}
 
    Canada Research Chair in Artificial Intelligence
    and Medical Imaging
    
    Member of the College of the Royal Society of 
    Canada
    
    Associate Professor

  \dots

  Phone: 123-456-7890

  \url{http://www.I.just.called.com}

  \vspace*{2cm}

 \today
 \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

% ~~~ TOC ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\tableofcontents
\newpage

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\section{PERSONAL DATA}
\textbf{Alexander Wong, P.Eng.}

Canada Research Chair in Artificial Intelligence and Medical Imaging

Member of the College of the Royal Society of Canada

\dots

\url{http://dont.forget.your.birthday}

\vspace{1cm}

\hrule
 \vspace{3mm}
  \textbf{EDUCATION AND RESEARCH POSITIONS}
 \vspace{3mm}
\hrule

% ~~~ directly ~~~~~~~~~~~~
%     the original is quite ad hoc, i.e. with little to no
%     regularity to exploit or refactor by simple macros
\bigskip
\textbf{University of Waterloo, Waterloo, ON} \hfill 2013-Present\par
\textit{Canada Research Chair in Artificial Intelligence and Medical Imaging (Tier II)}
\bigskip
\dots

\textbf{University of Waterloo, Waterloo, ON} \hfill 2011-Present\par
\textit{Associate Professor, Dept. of Systems Design Engineering (July 2016-Present)}
\textit{Assistant Professor, Dept. of Systems Design Engineering (May 2011-June 2016)}
\dots
\bigskip
\dots


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\section{RESEARCH AND SCHOLARSHIP}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{RESEARCH INTERESTS}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Deep-structured, random graph models for real-time, operational artificial intelligence
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Evolutionary deep intelligence for cross-generational deep architecture synthesis
 \item \dots
 \end{itemize}
 \item \dots
\end{itemize}
 
% ---
\subsection{PUBLICATIONS}
In the fields I work in, the lead authors and last authors are important. For papers co-authored with
students, the general policy is to list the students as \textbf{lead authors} unless \dots

% ~~~ REMARKS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\emph{!!! There are several approaches for the values of this table, like a) finish enumerated lists below and copy last value by hand, b) use a set of dedicated counters and extend macros to increment them etc.}\bigskip

Publication summary

\textbf{(h-index: 43, i10-index: 201)}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \toprule
    & Publications & IEEE & Citations\\
  \midrule
    Patents & 11 \\
    Conference papers & 310 & 124 \\
    \dots\\
  \midrule
   \textbf{Total} & \textbf{601} & \textbf{189} & \textbf{10341}\\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

 \subsubsection{Refereed Journal Papers (222)}
 % ~~~ REMARKS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \emph{!!! Use same approach as for talks, media coverage etc.}
 \subsubsection{Refereed Conference Papers (308)}
 \subsubsection{Patents and Patent Applications (38)}
 \subsubsection{Books and Book Chapters (7)}
 % ...
 \subsection{SELECTED AND INVITED PRESENTATIONS}
 \renewcommand\theenumi{T{\arabic{enumi}}}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item Invited Talk, Road to Operational AI: Advances and 
            Challenges, UW Student Venture Fund event, 2020.
  \item Invited Expert, OSFI Tech Risk Consultation - 
        Advanced Analytics Roundtable, Office of the 
        Superintendent of Financial Institutions, 2020.
  \item \dots
 \end{enumerate}

% ~~~ REMARKS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\emph{!!! Non-referenced: use same approach}

% ...
\subsection{MEDIA COVERAGE}
\renewcommand\theenumi{M{\arabic{enumi}}}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item ”Edge NLP Is About Doing More With Less,“ IoT World Today, January 2021.
 \item ”AI on AI on AI,“ The Rational View Podcast with Dr. Al Scott, January 2021.
 \item \dots
\end{enumerate}
% ...
\subsection{RESEARCH FUNDING}
\textbf{Total Funding \$9,687,794 in cash, \$1,197,653 in-kind}
% ...
\subsection{AWARDS}
% ~~~ directly ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\textbf{IMPACT 50} \hfill April 2020\par
\hspace{1ex}\textit{insideBIGDATA}\par
\textit{Awarded as Co-founder of DarwinAI for being one of the\\industry’s top 50 most impactful companies}
\bigskip

% ~~~ with above's macro, i.e. refactored ~~~~~~~~~~
\awrd{AI 100}
    {March 2020}
    {CB Insights}
    {Awarded as Co-founder of DarwinAI for being\\one of 100 most promising AI startups in the world}


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\section{SERVICE}
% ...
\subsection{COMMITEES}
\begin{itemize}
 % ~~~ refactored \item into macro \cmmt{}{} ~~~~~~~~~
 \cmmt{Member of the Artificial Intelligence undergraduate program committee}{2017 - present}
 \cmmt{Member of the Artificial Intelligence Institute committee}{2016 - present}
\end{itemize}
% ...
\subsection{EDITORIAL POSITIONS}
\begin{itemize}
 % ~~~ refactored \item into macro \edpos{}{}{} ~~~~~~~~~
 \edpos{Senior Editorial Board Member}
        {BMC Medical Imaging, Springer Nature.}
        {(2020-Present)} 
 \edpos{Section Editor}
        {BMC Medical Imaging, Springer Nature.}
        {(2015-2020)} 
\end{itemize}
% ...
\subsection{CONFERENCE ORGANIZATION}
\begin{itemize}
 % ~~~ refactored \item into macro \coorg{}{} ~~~~~~~~~
 \corg{Conference co-chair}
        {Annual Conference on Vision and Imaging Systems}
        {(CVIS 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018,2019,2020)}
 \corg{Technical program committee member}
        {BMVC Workshop on Visual Artificial Intelligence and
Entrepreneurship}
        {2019}
 \item \dots
\end{itemize}
% ...
\subsection{REVIEWING}
\begin{itemize}
 \item I serve as a reviewer for the following grants
 \begin{itemize}
  \item NSERC Discovery Grants.
  \item Canada Research Chair Grants.
 \end{itemize}
 \item I review five papers per month on average and have served as a reviewer for the following research journals,
conferences, and books:
 \begin{itemize}
  \item IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging.
  \item \dots
 \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\section{PROFESSIONAL ACTIVITIES}
\subsection{SOCIETY MEMBERSHIPS}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \textbf{Professional Engineer}, Professional Engineers of Ontario (PEO) (2010-Present) [with Certificate of
Authorization]
 \item Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE) (Senior Member) (2005-Present)
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Voting member on IEEE Communication Society Multimedia Communications Technical Committee
  \item Member on IEEE Computer Society Technical Committee on Pattern Analysis and Machine
Intelligence
 \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\subsection{STANDARDS COMMITTEE MEMBERSHIPS}
\begin{itemize}
\item Member, MC/ISO/IEC JTC 1/SC 42 - Artificial intelligence Committee, Standards Council of Canada
(2019-Present)
\item \dots
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```